# How do I use/load a xib in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a xib file which I created using `New -> iOS -> User Interface -> View`. Now I want to use my xib view inside a `UIViewController`. Say my xib is called dog. In the end I want to do something like

```
UIView *dog = ...;//load from xib
dog.frame = self.tableView.frame;//i.e. I want it to be the size of my tableview.
[self.view addSubView:dog];
```

then later I intend to remove the view, base on user action. So that's my question. Thus far I have been using storyboard so I don't know anything about loading a xib into a view controller. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your xib as a subview, you must use the following code inside your UIViewController:

```
UIView *dog = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Dog" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil].firstObject;
```

However, if you want to use the xib as the UIViewController view, you should assign the name of the UIViewController in the file's owner of the xib file.